# How configure eclipse for jsp formatting?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp

I want to configure eclipse so that:

My Original Code Format:

```
name: <input type="text" value="${event.name}" name="name" /> <br /> description: <input type="text" value="${event.description}"   name="description" /> <br />eventDate:<input    type="date" value="${event.eventDate}" name="resumeUrl" /><br />
```

My Target Code Format:

```
 name: <input type="text" value="${event.name}" name="name" /> 
 <br /> 
  description: 
 <input type="text" value="${event.description}"    name="description" /> 
 <br />
  eventDate:
 <input type="date" value="${event.eventDate}" name="resumeUrl" />
 <br />
```

I want to get `1 line = 1 tag` !

How to configure eclipse to reformat my original to target format?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In eclipse:

- for Windows Open Window Menu -> choose Preferences
- for Mac Open EclipceMenu -> choose Preferences

From the Preferences Window choose Web => HTML Files => Editor

From the `Inline Elements:` view, add all tags that you want appear in one line

Now whenever you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, the JSP will be formatted to your new style

Comment: You can go Eclipse Window - Preferences - Java - Editor - Save Actions. Check the "Perform the selected actions on save" and then check "Format source code". Now you format automatically your code when you save, a usefull tip related with the question.

Comment: @user1422434 .. Thank you for the tip .. just note that this will work only in `java` code files .. not `HTML` nor `JSP` code files.

Comment: Like @fujy said this doesn't work with JSP pages like the question asks.

Comment: @PhilipRego I am sorry, I don't understand your comment?

Comment: This solution just isn't working for me. I think it should but it's not for some reason. When my link tags are longer than the margin on the page it breaks on the attributes. I tried increasing the margin size, but no difference.

Comment: @PhilipRego, The question is about how to have each tag in its own line instead of having multiple tags in the same line. This is different from your problem, that is about a tag with long attribute, I suggest that you try to increase the `Line width:` field in the same window till your tag fits in one line .

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this:
Window -> Preference -> Web -> HTML Files ->Editor ->
Formatting : change the "Line width" to 200 or larger

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CTL+SHIFT+F` in eclipse but make sure you have opened jsp in jsp editor.

if not then go to Eclipse - window - preferences - general - editors - File Associations

and select file type as *.jsp and set JSP Editor as default

Comment: Yes Yes. But question about how configure in  window - preferences - web - jsp Files - editor

Answer (score 0):

From eclipse Window Menu, choose Preferences

From the Preferences Window choose Web => HTML Files => Editor

Increase the 
line widths and format the jsp page using `ctrl+shift+F`.

Answer (score -2):

No you can't simply format jsp(html & jsp scriplets) pages using ctrl+shift+f, if you use that keys it will make your code change the syntax, for example:

```
{
    String error = request.getAttribute("error") != null ? (String) request.getAttribute("error"): "";%>
}
```

this code will change it to

```
{
    String error = request.getAttribute("error") != null ? (String) request.getAttribute("error") : "";%> 
},
```

after using the keys again you have to manually align this scriplets